# I get a "attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.a'" error when I try to statically link libc++abi.a

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, g++, ld

### environment

- ubuntu 18.04 (a virtual environment created by vagrant)
- gcc5.5.0

I'm trying to build my own little OS.
I'm writing the kernel in C++/NASM.

I'm going to compile each of the several C++ files that make up the kernel and then link them together to create an executable file. (This is because the entry point of my own kernel is not "main", so I dare not link at the same time as compiling)

### Error

The compilation of each C++ file will run without any problems and each object file will be created.
However, I get the following error in linking the object files.

But I understand that a ".a" file is a static object, not a dynamic object, so I can not understand why I'm getting this error.

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

```
ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.a'
```

Here's the full text of the log

```
mkdir -p ./obj
g++ -O2 -g -MMD -Wall -I./include -o obj/hoge.o -c src/hoge.cpp
mkdir -p ./obj
g++ -O2 -g -MMD -Wall -I./include -o obj/huga.o -c src/huga.cpp
mkdir -p ./obj
g++ -O2 -g -MMD -Wall -I./include -o obj/piyo.o -c src/piyo.cpp
mkdir -p ./obj
nasm -f elf64 -o obj/assm.o src/assm.asm
ld --entry <ENTRY_POINT> --static -o ./ELF/kernel.elf ./obj/hoge.o ./obj/huga.o ./obj/piyo.o ./obj/assm.o -lc -lc++ -lc++abi -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.a'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'ELF/kernel.elf' failed
make: *** [ELF/kernel.elf] Error 1
```

### Makefile

```
COMPILER  = g++
CFLAGS    = -O2 -g -MMD -Wall
INCLUDE   = -I./include
TARGET    = ./ELF/kernel.elf
SRCDIR    = ./src
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name *.asm)
OBJDIR    = ./obj
OBJECTS   = $(OBJDIR)/hoge.o $(OBJDIR)/huga.o $(OBJDIR)/piyo.o $(OBJDIR)/assm.o
DEPENDS   = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
LDFLAGS = --entry <ENTRY_POINT> --static
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) -lc -lc++ -lc++abi -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    -mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.asm
    -mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    nasm -f elf64 -o $@ $<

all: clean $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(TARGET)

-include $(DEPENDS)
```

Comment: For your own kernel you can't really use the normal standard libraries (C or C++) as they depend on OS-support for much of their functionality, OS-support that doesn't exist in a kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was trying to use the standard libc or libc++. This was a mistake. If I link the libc and libc++ binaries built for other original OS, the error message has changed. It's not the same as the title error but I'm going to leave this post until it's resolved. Thank you so much!